# Android: MapView not responding after Resume

Tags: android, background, android-mapview

I have a strange problem with a com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.
To check if my App crashes after the garbage collector is doing his job i force my HTC One (4.2.2) to allow only 1 running app in background. If I leave my app(home button) while showing a MapView, start any other app and resume to my app, my MapView is still showing up...but I can not move or zoom the map, it's not responding at all. Other activities are working fine. I really have no clue where the problem might be.

Hope that someone can help me out?

Here is the sourcecode of my fragment that shows the MapView
    public class FragmentAdvertlistMap extends Fragment {

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView m;
GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<Advert> ads;
HashMap<Marker, String> myMarker;
public final LatLngBounds.Builder builder= new LatLngBounds.Builder();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO handle this situation
    }
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_advert_tab2, container, false);
    m = (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map_tab);
    m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myMarker = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
    ads= AdvertListActivity.getAdverts();
    setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AdvertLocationActivity.class);

            Advert putadvert = DefaultApplication.dbc.getAdvertForAdvertID(Integer.parseInt(myMarker.get(arg0)));

            myIntent.putExtra("advert", putadvert);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
    return inflatedView;
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map_tab)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            this.initMarker();
        }
    }
}

public void initMarker(){
    for(int i=0;i<ads.size();i++){
        Advert tempAd = ads.get(i);
        LatLng tlalo =  new LatLng(tempAd.mainLocation.latitude,tempAd.mainLocation.longitude);

        builder.include(tlalo);

        String address = "";
        if(tempAd.mainLocation.contact_street != null){
            address = address + tempAd.mainLocation.contact_street;
        }
        if(tempAd.mainLocation.contact_street_number != null){
            address = address + " " + tempAd.mainLocation.contact_street_number;
        }
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(tlalo)
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title(tempAd.name)
        .snippet(address)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.androidpin)));

        myMarker.put(marker,String.valueOf(tempAd.myid));
    }



mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 100));
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
    }

});
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    m.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    m.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    m.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    m.onLowMemory();
}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and/or printing log statements to determine the hang up here?

Comment: sadly there is no crash or error. LogCat shows nothing and I can not debug because the debugger will be disconnected the moment the other app starts.

Comment: You'll need to add log statements in your code, for them to show up in logcat.. I dont see Log.d("",""); anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

try add this in onCreateView()

```
container.removeAllViews();
```

I found it in another similar question to yours but I lost the original link of the answer...